# Type safety in Kotlin doesn't work as expected

Tags: kotlin

I have a code like this:

```
enum class Player { PLAYER, COMPUTER }

interface BoardCell {
    val x: Int
    val y: Int
    var player: Player?
}

data class Cell(val x: Int, val y: Int, var player: Player?, var value: Int)
data class BoardCellClass(override val x: Int, override val y: Int, override var player: Player?) : BoardCell
data class Request(val board: MutableList<MutableList<BoardCellClass>>? = null, val occupied: MutableList<BoardCellClass>? = null)

class AI(board: MutableList<MutableList<BoardCell>>, private var occupied: MutableList<BoardCell>) {
    private var board: MutableList<MutableList<Cell>> = board.map { it.map { Cell(it.x, it.y, it.player, 0) } .toMutableList() } .toMutableList()
}

// in main

val request = call.receive<Request>()

if (request.board == null || request.occupied == null) {
    // respond with 403
} else {
    val ai = AI(request.board, request.occupied) // Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is MutableList<MutableList<BoardCellClass>>? but MutableList<MutableList<BoardCell>> was expected
                                                 // Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is MutableList<BoardCellClass>? but MutableList<BoardCell> was expected
}
```

But it errors with what is in the comment in the bottom. What am I doing wrong? Clearly, there is an if statement, that catches nullity, so it shouldn't be of type `MutableList<MutableList<BoardCellClass>>?`, but `MutableList<MutableList<BoardCellClass>>`, no?
Also, `MutableList<MutableList<BoardCellClass>>` is compatible with `MutableList<MutableList<BoardCell>>`, because it implements that interface, right?

Comment: Could you show what is `call` and what `receive<Request>()` returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MutableList> is compatible with
>   MutableList>, because it implements that
>   interface, right?

No. In your case you can use [`out`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) keyword

```
class AI(board: MutableList<MutableList<BoardCell>>, private var occupied: MutableList<out BoardCell>) {
    private var board: MutableList<MutableList<Cell>> = board.map { it.map { Cell(it.x, it.y, it.player, 0) } .toMutableList() } .toMutableList()
}
```

> Clearly, there is an if statement, that catches nullity, so it
>   shouldn't be of type

You can write this code in if (not else) part to compiler understand you in wright way

```
if (request.board != null && request.occupied != null){
     val ai = AI(request.board, request.occupied)
} else {
    // respond with 403
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Also, `MutableList<MutableList<BoardCellClass>>` is compatible with `MutableList<MutableList<BoardCell>>`, because it implements that interface, right?

No, it isn't. That's an issue of [*variance*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance). Searching for "Kotlin variance" will give you many explanations, but the simplest way to see why `MutableList<BoardCellClass>` isn't a subtype of `MutableList<BoardCell>` is

```
val list: MutableList<BoardCellClass> = ...
val list1: MutableList<BoardCell> = list // illegal in actual Kotlin!
list1.add(object : BoardCell { ... }) // would add a BoardCell to a MutableList<BoardCellClass>
```

Then the same logic can be lifted up a level to see that `MutableList<MutableList<BoardCellClass>>` isn't a subtype of `MutableList<MutableList<BoardCell>>`.

> Clearly, there is an if statement, that catches nullity, so it shouldn't be of type `MutableList<MutableList<BoardCellClass>>?`, but `MutableList<MutableList<BoardCellClass>>`, no?

That's not quite how Kotlin smart casts work (though the difference isn't relevant most of the time). It's still of type `MutableList<MutableList<BoardCellClass>>?`, but if it's used where the required type is `MutableList<MutableList<BoardCellClass>>`, it's automatically cast. Here the required type is `MutableList<MutableList<BoardCell>>` instead, and so there's no cast inserted and the nullable type shows up in the error message.